# PHP SoapClient - Error Fetching http headers

Tags: php, laravel, wsdl, soap-client

I'm using PHP SoapClient to fetch details from a soap api, it works perfectly before, then suddenly it stops working and giving me this error: (with a status of 200 OK)

```
{
    "faultstring": "Error Fetching http headers",
    "faultcode": "HTTP"
}
```

This is my code: (that runs perfectly before)

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace"=>1, "exceptions"=>0));
```

**Things I've tried:**

disabling keep_alive

- `'keep_alive' => 0`

increasing timeout from php.ini

- `default_socket_timeout = 6000`

increasing timeout from php code

- `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 6000);`

disabling wsdl cache from php.ini

- `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0`

tried compression header

- `'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE`

**But no luck**

Don't know what I'm missing

Thanks for the help

---

My machine:

PHP: `PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Apache: `Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Sometimes the webservers "KeepAlive"-Setting tends to result in this error. For SOAP-Environments I recommend you to disable KeepAlive.

Comment: You mean disable KeepAlive from SOAP server? I'm requesting from my local machine to remote SOAP server.